# Vscode intellisense is slow when using WSL , not on windows

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, javascript-intellisense

I have a project that I am working on right now, everytime I use WSL the intellisense takes roughly 15 second per file to load meanwhile on Windows it's like close to instant.

Can I improve this in any way?

I am working with Javascript / React - using WSL (with vscode installed on windows 10)

cpu : amd r9 3900x
ram : 32go 3800mhz
gpu : rtx 3080

I'm using WSL 1 with Debianvm - VS Code 1.75.1

I tried to enable / disable my extensions which didn't work.
I used windows without WSL and it's instant there without any hiccups.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? For me, with WSL, VS Code takes 10 minutes after each start before auto-complete works, even for builtins.